# Windows Azure SDK for Node.js SQL Azure Provider

Tags: sql, node.js, azure

I want to connect to SQL Azure using Node.js SDK for Windows Azure but there are no tutorials about how to set it up.  Does anybody know how I can talk to a SQL Azure DB using Node.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a discussion about this topic, on [this MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/e138828e-9181-4b19-94d6-fb2058e6a5a6/). Per Nate Totten's comment, there's no official driver, but there are a few community-driven ones on Joyent's [github repo](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-mssql). I haven't been able to find any additional information about this.

Answer (score 3):

We've released a preview version of the Microsoft Driver for Node.JS for SQL Server (and Windows Azure SQL Database a.k.a. SQL Azure) last week!

You can find it on Github:
https://github.com/windowsazure/node-sqlserver/

Thanks,

Jonathan

Comment: I second that... and since you asked for a tutorial, here you go :) https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, I would suggest if you really have to connect to SQL Azure, the following has **comparatively richer** implementation then any other:

https://github.com/cretz/node-tds

Comment: I don't believe that node-tds supports SQL Azure (now known as Windows Azure SQL Database) based on [this issue](https://github.com/cretz/node-tds/issues/14) which is still active.